# How to extend LVM in RHEL 5.6

Tags: linux, rhel, lvm

I need to extend the LVM on one server. This is the output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/cciss/c0d0p2      58G   26G   29G  48% /
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      476G   86G  366G  19% /u001/app/oracle
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1     487M   17M  445M   4% /boot
tmpfs                  16G  730M   16G   5% /dev/shm
```

And I need to extend `/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00` from 475G to 700G. I have enough space to do this.

Any suggestions? *Please mention all steps and prerequisites*

#### Further Details

Before I go and apply this on actual server. I first plan to do this on a virtual machine. So I installed 5.6 on VirtualBox and assigned 25GB for installation.

`df -h` result:

[image: df -h]

And when I used the command

```
lvextend -L +500M /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVoll00
```

its reply was “insufficient space”.

[image: lvextend]

Although there is uninitialized space ready to be used.

[image: vgdisplay]

Seems it didn't work. Please advice what's wrong here.

#### Output of `vgs` and `pvs` commands

[image: vgs & pvs]

Comment: There is *not* "uninitialized space ready to be used".  `Free  PE / Size       0 / 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, check that you really have already space on your VG. In your example "Free PE" is 0, so you cannot extend any LV in it. If you do not have space on that VG, please add create new PEs with command `pvcreate` and add them to VG with command `vgextend`. Once you have enough space, just estend your LV with command `lvextend` and then resize your file system.

Comment: Ok dear. As there was no Free space so by using pvcreate i created Physical drive and then ***vgextend VolGroup00 /dev/PathToPart*** and finally I used ***lvextend /dev/VolumeGroup00/Logvol -l 100%VG*** and then used resize2fs to update the Logical Volume.

Answer (score 2):

first make sure required size available or not on your physical volume using :

```
$ vgs
```

then try below to extend:

```
$ lvextend –L +500M /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
$ resize2fs /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
```

Comment: Dear I have added the details in question under Further Details section Thanks

Comment: Hi,
it's seems your volume group already used , you need to extend your pv and vg first then you can extend your lv